# passing a dynamic value through <a> tag?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to pass a dynamic value through an anchor tag as if through a submit.

So far I have it working when the href if clicked like so::

html:

```
<td>
    <a href='#' data-val='".$row['client_id']."' class='formAnchor'>
        ".$row['first_name']. " " .$row['last_name'] ."
    </a>
</td>"
```

js.

```
$('.formAnchor').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#client_id').val($(this).data('val'));
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
});
```

So I have a hidden input in my html page and when ever the link (the a tag) is clicked the above javascript first prevents the default action (loading the href location) then appends the value from the a tag to the hidden field then submits the form.

This works when I click the link, it submits the value and I do `$_GET['value']` and get the value on the other page.

Now what I can't seem to do is when I try to rightclick the href and open it in new tab it doesn't submit the value as I want it to.

The best example I can think of what I am trying to do would be the way on facebook when you click a profile link (name of the person) it gives you that particular persons profile and it also works when you rightclick and open in new tab.

Comment: Please fix the quotes in the question (and answer). You have no opening `"` quotes in what's clearly PHP code starting in the middle of a `"`-quoted string.

Answer (score 0):

I had been doing some search online and it hit me just now: Since I'm expecting a GET, I can just use a link, no JavaScript required:

```
<td><a href='profile.php?client_id=".$row['client_id']."' data-val='".$row['client_id']."' class='formAnchor'> ".$row['first_name']. " " .$row['last_name'] ."</a></td>"
```